# Retrieve Individual character from varchar field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can I retrieve individual characters of field values (e.g A - C - D from value ACD) and manipulate in SQL Server if I have a column of type `varchar(4)` with following variable length values.

```
Column
---
ACD                           
BC                            
CD
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the individual character?  Which individual character do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, column is of length 4, so I want to get each 4 characters, whether letter exists at a certain position or not. once I have the characters, I want to manipulate to another desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  case when CHARINDEX('A', columnName, 1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end has_a,
        case when CHARINDEX('B', columnName, 1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end has_b,
        case when CHARINDEX('C', columnName, 1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end has_c,
        case when CHARINDEX('D', columnName, 1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end has_d
from    tableName
```

Comment: paul - can I have Y & N from above query instead of 1 & 0?

Comment: yes, you can: `case when CHARINDEX('A', columnName, 1) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end has_a`

Answer (score 2):

You may use SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ABC',1,1)
```

The first param is the input string, the second one is the start index 1-based, and the third is the length of the result.

So if you have a column Col1 in a table Table1:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1,1,1),
       SUBSTRING(Col1,2,1),
       SUBSTRING(Col1,3,1),
       SUBSTRING(Col1,4,1)
FROM   Table1
```

You will get an empty string if for instance you have three characters and you try to get the fourth.

[`Fiddle Example Here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4fec/2)